# Replace all instances of base class with child class C#

Tags: c#

This is a bit hard to explain in the title, but here's my situation. I have existing code and use the standard Textbox throughout. I have decided that I need to add functionality to the Textbox class so I created MyTextbox derived from Textbox and added what I needed. Now I want to permanently use MyTextbox instead of Textbox. I Should be able to force all instances of Textbox (present and future) to use MyTextbox.

I have done something similar before in C++ along the tune of

```
    typedef Textbox MyTextbox;
```

If this makes sense, is it possible to do in C#?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question, but why couldn't you just do a find/replace on Textbox to MyTextbox?  Here's a similar question on MSDN: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharplanguage/thread/019a258e-8d50-4a9f-b0ef-8311208ebb6a

Comment: That's a initial solution, but it doesn't prevent others from using TextBox in the future.

Could you write a custom FxCop or StyleCop rule that will tell people in your project not to use TextBox directly?

Comment: Yeah I had heard this suggestion and it might work but I guess I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution. I guess it's just easier in C++ to global typedef it and then it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

Why not do a mass find/replace across your solution? This can be done quite easily in Visual Studio.

You could do the following at the top of each file that uses a `Textbox`:

```
using Textbox = Custom.Namespace.MyTextbox;
```

I don't recommend this because anyone seeing what looks like the standard text box in your code may not realize it is in fact your own custom text box. This may also cause ambiguity when compiling the related code.

Comment: I think this might be what I'm after. The whole goal is to make it as easy as possible to future programmers to use rather than say hey use MyTextbox instead of Textbox. I also heard a suggestion to put some protection in the top level that asserts if anyone tries to use a regular Textbox.

Comment: Up to you, but as @SirPentor suggested, implement a custom FxCop or StyleCop rule to ensure that no future developer uses the standard `Textbox`, otherwise there is no way to prevent this.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to make sure that your new functionality is available to everyone who uses TextBox instead of MyTextBox is to use extension methods. Then you wouldn't have to worry about the user using the wrong class.

MSDN Article on Extension Methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why would you need to refer TextBox class again if you already have created MyTextBox. Remember, MyTextBox has all the functionality from TextBox and its own functionality as well.

In case you want to change all existing textboxes from your to comply to MyTextBox, you have to go manual. Edit them all because even if you change the type from .Net Framweork Base Class Library, exceptions would be thrown wherever a TextBox is called